# Horizontal-Oriented ListBoxItems won't stretch

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, listbox

I am trying to stretch the ListBoxItems when using a WrapPanel and Orientation="Horizontal":

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <!--Some Textboxes and Labels-->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

If I don't use the WrapPanel it will expand the ListBoxItems to match the size of the ListBox. When I use the WrapPanel, the ListBoxItems have the minimum Width.

Briefly:

I have a list with two ListBoxItems Oriented Horizontally:

[image: A list with two Items]

When I expand the Main Window, the ListBox will also expand since I have HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" but the ListBoxItems won't.
[image]

So what I want is the ListBoxItems to expand with the ListBox like the example below:

[image: The same list after I expanded the Window]

Is there a better Control other than the ListBox for this scenario?
Please let me know if this is not clear enough.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't try this out to see if it is the problem, but try adding IsItemsHost="true" to the WrapPanel. [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.isitemshost.aspx)

Comment: @Wonko the Sane Just tried it and didn't seem to make any difference :(

Comment: Also set your HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" for the WrapPanel?

Comment: @Wonko the Sane Done that already but still no luck...

Comment: sorry - without being able to try some stuff out at the moment, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: By the way, if you don't need item selection i would recommend using an `ItemsControls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a `UniformGrid` as the `ItemsPanel` like so:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <!--Some Textboxes and Labels-->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a horizontal wrap panel and also expect elements to stretch horizontally, it's a logcal contradiction of interests. Actually, if you want *any* kind of stretching a `WrapPanel` is probably not the right panel.

If you want them to take equal space while overall taking all horizontal space there is then use a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) (set `Rows` to one).

Comment: Is there any other way that I can achieve a Horizontal Orientation without using a WrapPanel (or a StackPanel which I've also tried) and also Stretch the ListBoxItems?

Comment: @Aris: So you want the items stacked from left to right and you also want to stretch them from left to right? That would still be a logical contradiction, it's impossible, you have to have some concrete width if you lay them out horizontally.

Comment: @Aris - perhaps an image of what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful here.

Comment: @Aris: If you want them to take equal space while overall taking all horizontal space there is then use a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) (set `Rows` to one).